# Meteor Removed autopublish and insecure But return current user all data from Client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, meteor

In My Meteor Project Remove **autopublish** and **insecure** packages . I didn't write publishing code from server, but after Login retrieve User Data from the Server. But I want to have some specific data only shown client-side while others are private. How do I do this?

> Note: I'm using Meteor with react for the front end.

Comment: I don't think there is other why without writing a publish function. I am not sure why is it giving you all data even after removing publish and insecure.

Comment: Can you give more details as to how you retrieve data? the method you use?